# How to customize tableView Section View - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I know how to customize the tableViewCell.

I have seen many application customizing the tableView Cell.

Similarly, I want to customize TableView Section Header

"Suppose - A section name should be in different font, It has different background images etc."

Is it possible How?

In which method Should I implement the code?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Instead of using the normal method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You want to implement this one:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

As you can see, the second one returns a UIView instead of just string for text.  Therefore you can customise your own view (with labels etc) and return it.

Here is an example of how you might do that (to be implemented in the above method):

```
// create the parent view that will hold header Label
UIView* customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,300,60)] autorelease];

// create image object
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];;

// create the label objects
UILabel *headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70,18,200,20);
headerLabel.text =  @"Some Text";
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

UILabel *detailLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
detailLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
detailLabel.text = @"Some detail text";
detailLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
detailLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70,33,230,25);

// create the imageView with the image in it
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] autorelease];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);

[customView addSubview:imageView];
[customView addSubview:headerLabel];
[customView addSubview:detailLabel];

return customView;
```

Comment: If your table had two sections for example, how would you reference that second table section, so section header 1 would have a different headerLabel.text than section header 2?

Comment: By the integer that's passed into the method.

Comment: What if I want to only have a header for section = 1 and not for section = 0? I am having an issue with this problem...

Comment: I don't remember that far back but I figure you could just as simply return a null view for the case indexPath.section == 0 and for indexPath.section == 1 return the custom view

Comment: @jsetting32 Why don't you guys play with heightForHeaderInSection, for section == 0 give some height and for section ==1 return 0