# How to customize tableView Section Header with a XIB?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I am attempting to create customized section headers for a UITableView. I have found a few references illustrating how to do this completely in code (#[1349571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349571/how-to-customize-tableview-section-view-iphone)).

I am trying to determine if it is possible to create a UIView in Interface Builder and use that to customize the header similar to how it is possible to do this for a UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 6):

YES It is possible to use header view created using XIB. Create a XIB and the class to manage the XIB (UIView class). Use

```
YourNibClassName* v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOUR_XIB_NAME" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];

//With this method you can load any xib for header view

tableView.tableHeaderView = v;
[v release];
```

**EDIT**

Return this view in the viewForHeaderInSection like this

```
YourNibClassName* v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOUR_XIB_NAME" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
//Do some stuff here like setting text on labels etc.
return [v autorelease];
```

Answer (score 4):

Since we have prototype cells, you can also add a prototype cell to your table.
Fill in the Identifier of the prototype cell in Interface Builder. (for example HeaderCell)
You can then use it in viewForHeaderForSection like you use cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HeaderCellID];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:100];
    label.text = [self tableView:self.tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why I never thought of this before. Works well and way easier for any complex headers, especially when using auto layout, took out a lot of constant code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add it as labels above the table and remove the stranded table header I did that once I know it sound weird but worked