# Custom layout in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am coding an iPhone App in which am using a UITableView which has several sections ; each section has a header & then its rows like this:

[image]

I can do the row styles correctly, by using custom UITableViewCell objects, but how do I do the header? As you can see:

1. the header has the text centered with two lines drawn from it, one on each side
2. The header color is different
3. also the corners of each section are rounded

how do I achieve this, either programmatically or using Storyboard?

Comment: [How to customize tableView Section View](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1349657/1059705) this may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

This method, implemented as part of your UITableViewDelegate, is intended to allow you to to create custom views for headers in UITableViews.  You can return any UIView from that method, whether it's one that you want to create in Interface Builder, or in code.

Comment: being pedantic, you must implement it in your UITableViewDelegate delegate, not override it

Comment: Thank you! Let me try it out! I knew this method earlier, but not sure if it can render a completely different looking header ; let me try it. Thanks!