# Customize a table view section header in a storyboard rather than programmatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to customize the table view section header of a static table, this can be done programmatically ([How to customize tableView Section View - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349571/how-to-customize-tableview-section-view-iphone)).

However is there a way of having the header view and designing its layout graphically within a storyboard?

(If not I could use a .xib to hold the view, but having it in the storyboard in the actual table would be more convenient)

Similarly for the main table header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drag a UIView at the top of your UITableView and you are good to go :).

EDIT:

For the section headers you can add another cell in your table in storyboard and programmatically choose between the two cells depending on whether it's a header or not.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the main header, but can't drag a view for the section headers.

Comment: The section headers need to be done programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just use xib to define section header/footer, then in method `-[tableView sectionHeaderForIndexPath:]` return the header/footer view defined in an xib file.

As we known, storyboard can include only segues and scenes. That's to say, a customized view defined in a scene can NOT be reused in another scene. So, xib is the best solution.